# What is the order of this pole at $\pi/2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider:
$$f(z)=\frac{\cos(z)}{(z-\pi/2)^4}$$ at $z = \pi/2$.

What is the order of the pole?  How can I see this?  I keep getting $2$, but my textbook says that the answer is $3$.

Comment: Can you write down the Taylor series for $\cos z$ at $\pi/2$? (The first few terms suffice.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\frac{\cos z}{(z-\pi/2)^4}=\frac{-(z-\pi/2)+\frac1{3!}(z-\pi/2)^3+O((z-\pi/2)^5)}{(z-\pi/2)^4}=\\-\frac1{(z-\pi/2)^3}+\frac1{3!}\,\frac1{z-\pi/2}+O(z-\pi/2)
$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{3!}(z-\pi/2)^3$.

Comment: I see my error.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, corrected.